# App engine runs go 1.5, release notes says 1.6

Tags: google-app-engine, go

According to the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/release-notes) app engine should be running go 1.6 but if I try to use [iris](https://github.com/kataras/iris) it fails because it requires 1.6. "go version" from shell also returns 1.5!

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your app engine version 1.9.35 or greater? That's the release where Go was bumped to 1.6.

Comment: I'm using go version go1.6 (appengine-1.9.36) windows/amd64

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `go version` try `goapp version`. The App Engine SDK requires a wrapper script because it sets a custom `GOPATH`.

Comment: ~$ goapp version
go version go1.4.2 (appengine-1.9.33) linux/amd64

Comment: This means you are not using the latest App Engine Go SDK. After installing the newer SDK, `goapp version` should show `go version go1.6 (appengine-1.9.36) linux/amd64` and you'll be able to use Go 1.6 features.

Comment: Ah, so you're using Cloud Shell. The App Engine SDK was updated, but Cloud Shell was not. If you want to use App Engine with Go 1.6, you're going to need to either install the SDK locally, or wait until Cloud Shell gets updated. https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#language_support